# Append counts of discrete values in legend of a PCA ggbiplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to mention the count of each discrete values in the legend of a PCA plot I made with ggbiplot (I used ggbiplot because it's simple to draw ellipses).

My code:

```
# dummy dataset
df <- iris[-5]

# the labels to display in the legend
count_legend <- paste0(levels(iris$Species)," (", table(iris$Species),")")

# the PCA plot
ggbiplot(prcomp(df), obs.scale = 1, var.scale = 1, groups=iris$Species, ellipse=T, varname.size=0, var.axes=F) +
scale_fill_discrete(labels=count_legend)
```

The `scale_fill_discrete` part usually works with other type of plots (e.g. barplot, etc), but not with ggbiplot.

Comment: Where does `ggbiplot` come from? There are functions with this name in several packages, and even a package with this name. I get an error trying to run this, and I'm assuming it's because this is from a package I don't have installed

Comment: https://github.com/vqv/ggbiplot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you want something like this?

```
# the PCA plot
ggbiplot(prcomp(df), obs.scale = 1, var.scale = 1, groups=iris$Species, ellipse=T, varname.size=0, var.axes=F) +
scale_color_discrete(labels=count_legend)
```

[image]